# How to add authorized client to xhost?

Tags: linux, x11, display, x-server, xhost

Om a linux machine (In this case Debian), when I use the xhost command as follows:

```
$ xhost +
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
$ xhost -
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
```

When I do `xhost -` I observe `authorized clients` are allowed...

Is there a way that I can add a authorised client? So that, even with `xhost -` specific clients/users can access the server.

Comment: `$ xhost +SI:localuser:<username>
localuser:<username> being added to access control list`
I could add a local user using the above command. However, it is not a permanent change. The user is removed when I logout of desktop session or reboot the machine. I am looking for a permanent solution to this...